# SQL Server ETL process transaction logs

Tags: sql-server, backup, etl

is it ok to set recovery mode simple in a staging db for an ETL process... The customer is not even doing a regular backup! So what's the point in keeping the transaction logs...

I propose to organize a daily backup after the bulk import and that's it...

Anything against this plan? Also the transaction logs were at 80gb after 3 weeks...

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would use simple mode. In fact, I do...

The data does not require "point in time recovery" so make life easier for yourself. Do you even need a full backup?